# Can JPA entity beans contain methods to add objects to Collection fields?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jpa, entity

I have several JPA entities that have one-to-many relationships to other entities and therefore contain Collection fields. Obviously, as per the standard bean pattern I have getter and setter methods for these Collections but it would also be useful to have methods to add and remove objects/entities from these collections. Would I be breaking bean conventions to add these methods to the entity class themselves? If this is the case, what would be the best way of implementing these methods? I do have Facade EJBs for each entity which I could use for this purpose but these are primarily concerned with DB access logic (persist, remove, etc) and obtaining data structures (lists, etc) rather than manipulating the entity itself.

Comment: I believe it is OK to have this kind of utility methods in the entities themselves.

Comment: I agree with @NikosParaskevopoulos. Adders and removers are common practice for JPA entities.

Comment: Excellent! That makes life considerably easier. I really didn't want to add another layer to the application if I could avoid it. As far as StackOverflow etiquette goes, if I set this question as answered, Nikos won't get the rep for it as the answer is in the comments. What's the protocol?

Comment: I think you should answer and accept your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Nikos Paraskevopoulos and Flying Dumpling for the answer. It would appear that utility methods are permissible within an entity class.